# woocommerce rest api OAuth authentication in android

Tags: android, oauth

what is the sample code for OAuth 1.0a(one leg) authentication in android?
is there a library for it? .
I use eclipse and i'm new in android. can anyone clarify the path for me?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @VipulKumar thanks for reminding. now you can see the answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to answer my own question:

1. download Scrib.jar library and add it to your lib folder(you can download it from ([here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.scribe/scribe/1.3.0))
2. create a class with name "OneLeggedApi10" and copy below code in it:

   ```
   import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
   import org.scribe.model.Verb;
   import org.scribe.model.Token;
   public class OneLeggedApi10 extends DefaultApi10a  {
   @Override
   public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public Verb getAccessTokenVerb() {
       return Verb.GET;
   }

   @Override
   public Verb getRequestTokenVerb() {
       return Verb.GET;
   }
   }
   ```
3. now you can do OAuth authentication:

   ```
   String RESOURCE_URL = "http://yourDomain.com/wc-api/v3/orders";
   String SCOPE = "*"; //all permissions
   Response response;
   OAuthRequest request;
   String responsebody = "";
   OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(OneLeggedApi10.class)
                   .apiKey("your_key")                
                   .apiSecret("your_apiSecret") 
                   .signatureType(SignatureType.QueryString)
                   .debug()
                   /*.scope(SCOPE).*/
                   .build();

               request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, RESOURCE_URL);
               service.signRequest(new Token("", ""), request);

               // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
               Log.d("scribe","Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
               try{
                   response = request.send();
                   if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                       responsebody  = response.getBody();
                   }

               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
   ```
4. note that if you are not using above code in an AsyncTask,then put the request.send() part in a thread (actually whole try_catch section) for avoiding run in main thread exception
5. finally if you want to send data,for example in a case that you want to update an order,replace

   ```
    request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, RESOURCE_URL);
   ```

   with these lines:

   ```
   String payload = yourJsonOBJ.toString();
   request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PUT, RESOURCE_URL);
   request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   request.addPayload(payload);
   ```

more information in [WooCommerce Documentation site](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)
Hope it help ;)
good luck..

Comment: thank you, it is working. But response has a limit while assigning to that `String`. How can I get that in JSON format?

Comment: in scribe library it only returns response in a single String.this way it supports a response with almost 2^31=2147483648 characters. check this page that shows Response class of scribe: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.scribe/scribe/1.3.0/org/scribe/model/Response.java#Response.0stream

Comment: @Moradi gives an error Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter; on this line service.signRequest(new Token("", ""), request);, How do I solve it ??

Answer (score 2):

```
new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    String RESOURCE_URL = "http://www.woocommerce.com/wp-json/wc/v1/api/";
                    String SCOPE = "*"; //all permissions
                    Response response;
                    OAuthRequest request;
                    String responsebody = "";
                    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(OneLeggedApi10.class)
                            .apiKey("yourConsumerKey")
                            .apiSecret("yourConsumerSecret")
                            .signatureType(SignatureType.QueryString)
                            .debug()
                            /*.scope(SCOPE).*/
                            .build();

                    request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, RESOURCE_URL);
                    service.signRequest(new Token("", ""), request);

                    // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
                    Log.d("scribe","Now we're going to access a protected resource...");

                try {
                    response = request.send();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        responsebody = response.getBody();
                        Log.v("response", responsebody);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

This code is updated from above, the above code is working getting JSON from wordpress Woocommerce API.
But if you wondering how to use Thread this is the answer.
And I add Log.v for see the json response.

Comment: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter; on                   service.signRequest(new Token("", ""), request); , How do i solve it ??