# In my android e-commerce app which uses my woocommerce inventory how can I create resources eg. customers, orders etc using the woocommerce rest api

Tags: android, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have my e-commerce store which uses woocommerce -a wordpress plugin. I need to develop my android app which performs all the CRUD operations for all the woocommerce resources eg customers, orders etc. For doing so I am using Woocommerce Rest Api : ref : http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/.

For client side authentication we need to pass consumer key and consumer secret. As suggested I am using OAuth1 authentication using scribe library. ref: [woocommerce rest api OAuth authentication in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167854/woocommerce-rest-api-oauth-authentication-in-android).

My problem is that while I am able to list all the resources like customers, products etc. I am unable to create them.

Please suggest me any other alternative which I can use to POST request to my woocommerce store.

Note : I even tried rest clients like Postman and ARC for testing but they were also unable to create resources.